# Is it possible to have a python class attribute be callable without ()

Tags: python, class, function, attributes

I want to do something a bit strange.  I want to be able to access a class attribute that can be accessed as either a non-function or function:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 99
    def x(self, *args, **kwargs ):
        print "x was called, args=%r, kwargs=%r" % (args, kwargs)
        return( self.x )  # return something useful here...

f = foo()
    print f.x  # prints "x was called", 99
    print f.x() # prints "x was called", 99
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Stort answer: you can use a property that returns a no-op lambda.

Comment: I want to let a user of this class be able to access "x" with or without parameters.  Yes, they would do f.x() but I am just curious if it's possible to have the f.x case be treated the same as the f.x() case.  Let me add a bit to the question...

Answer (score 3):

No idea *why* you would want to do that, but here is one way, using the [`property` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        print "x was called"
        return lambda: None
```

but this is *completely* nonsensical. It'll achieve what your example tries to do, but when you access `Foo().x` a lambda function is returned that is otherwise useless.

If you are fine with returning instances of a custom class, then you can also give that custom class a `__call__()` method that simply returns `self` to give `.x()` slightly more meaning:

```
class XReturnValue(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return self

class Foo(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        print "x was called"
        return XReturnValue()
```

where `XReturnValue` could be fleshed out more to actually mean something to the user of `Foo.x`.

However, in Python callables (such as functions and methods) are objects in and of themselves. You can manipulate them, add attributes to them, assign them to different variables for later use, etc.  To get their result you call them, but if you don't call them you can retrieve that reference to be re-used elsewhere. You should not try and circumvent that.

In other words, either stick with `.x` being an attribute, a `property`, or a method, but don't try to be all at once.

Comment: you say I can do what I want but not return anything useful.  I am too much of a newbie to understand why that is...

Comment: @staggart: Because objects in python are either callable or they are not. A function or a method is a callable; if you want it to do something you do just that, call it. If you don't call it, you have a reference to the callable, if you do call it you have the result of the call. To make return a result whether or not it is called goes against that.